# "Ты не ... ли часом?" - нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая перед "часом" в устоявшемся обороте "... не ... ли часом?"

[Корпус](https://ruscorpora.ru/results?search=Cj8qGAoICAAQChgyIAoQBSAAQAVqBDAuOTV4ADICCAE6AQFCHAoaChgKA3JlcRIRCg/Qu9C4INGH0LDRgdC%2B0LwwAQ==) ответа не дал - половина примеров с запятой, другая половина без. Так что непонятно - то ли запятая нужна, то ли не нужна, то ли и так и так сойдёт.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Обычная история:** слово "часом" может быть **наречием** со значением "иногда" (не обособляется) и "**вводным словом**" со значением "кстати, между прочим" (обособляется).

Поэтому семантика **разная**, выбор делается **по контексту.**

**[Словарь](https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BC&mode=all)**

**ЧАСОМ, вводное слово** (в вопросительном предложении, с частицей «не») То же, что «кстати, между прочим». Подробно о пунктуации при вводных словах и сочетаниях см. в Прил. 2. А ты, часом, не по-над речкою ли шел? В. Короленко, Судный день. Вы, девки, часом, сырой муки, в воде заболтавши, не ели? А. Солженицын, Случай на станции Кочетовка. !

**Не смешивать** с употреблением в роли члена предложения (в знач. «иногда»).

**Например:**

(1) *Не ты ли, **часом**, мне утром звонил? Я не успела подойти.*

Вводное слово "кстати".

(2) *Не ты ли **часом** звонишь, а потом молчишь. Или еще кто?*

Наречие "иногда".

Comment: К сожалению, ваш ответ не совсем проясняет. Слово "часом" в значении "иногда" употребляется очень редко - если вы по моей ссылке посмотрите корпус, то увидите, что оно там практически везде в значении "кстати", и запятая при этом ставится произвольно. Неграмотность корректоров?

Comment: У "иногда" много синонимов, посмотрите В Грамоте https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=иногда&mode=all Смотрю первые примеры в Нацкорпусе. Я бы так же поставила знаки. Между вводным словом и наречием трудно бывает ощутить разницу только по смыслу. Они легко заменяют друг друга.  Вводное слово - это авторская пометка на полях, а наречие входит в структуру предложения, грамматически связано с ним, в том числе по интонации. Приведите в своем вопросе примеры из Корпуса, в которых вы сомневаетесь, и я разберу их (семантика, структура, интонация).  Все там грамотно, наугад ставить знаки нельзя.

Comment: Да, вы правы - иногда (часом:) очень сложно уловить разницу.

Answer (score 1):

**Примеры из Нацкорпуса**

(1) *Валентин Алексеевич многозначительно ухмыльнулся и проговорил с ехидным подтекстом: — Уж не заболел ли, **часом** (= **сейчас**, в данный момент, случайно), старик? Тут и Железняцкий улыбнулся.*

(2) *— Заело тебя что-то, не сломалась ли, **часом** (= Сейчас, между прочим, кстати сказать)? — улыбнулся он еще шире.*

(3) *А не взлететь ли **часом** (= иногда, **порой**) в небеса?*

(4) *— Он... гельд взял и автосалон открыл, тысячи делает, а фатеру ни копья не вернул, паскуда!.. Не поможешь ли **часом** (= иногда, иной раз, по возможности)? Ты же вор с именем!*

**Примечание**

Отметим, что **прямое** значение слова ***"час"*** просматривается в примерах.

***Часом*** (наречие) — это иногда, **порою**, не в данный момент.

***Часом*** (вводное слово) относится  **текущему** моменту ( сейчас). Кроме того, при значении вводности это **попутное** замечание (= кстати, между прочим).